# Matrix inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbf{Z,R}$ two Hermitian semidefinite positive matrices with all eigenvalues larger than one. Intuition drives me that

> $\mathbf{R}^{-1/2}\mathbf{Z} \left(\mathbf{R}^{-1/2}\right)^H - \mathbf{Z} \preceq \mathbf{0}$

Any idea of how to proceed with the inequality verification?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be Hermitian positive definite matrices. Then, the following matrix
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
A & X\\
X^* & B
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
is positive definite *if and only if* $X=A^{1/2}ZB^{1/2}$ for some $Z$ that satisfies $\|Z\| \le 1$ (thus, the range of $X$ is a subspace of the range of $A$, and the range of $X^*$ is a subspace of the range of $B$).

To this matrix, apply the Schur-complement's lemma to conclude that
\begin{equation*}
 A \ge X^* B^{-1}X.
\end{equation*}

Using $X=R^{-1/2}$ and $B=A^{-1}$, we must therefore have
$R^{-1/2} = A^{1/2}ZA^{-1/2}$ for some contraction $Z$. If $R$ satisfies such an equality, the original claim will be true.

Comment: Nice derivation. Can I include you in the paper's acknowledgement ?

Comment: @mikitov: this is somewhat standard in matrix analysis, so I would at best say: "We thank Mathoverflow (linking to this post) for bringing to our attention a standard result that helps...."

Answer (score 2):

Not true.  Try
$$ R = \pmatrix{4 & 0\cr 0 & 10^4\cr},\ Z = \pmatrix{110 & 100\cr 100 & 100\cr} $$
$$ R^{-1/2} Z R^{-1/2} - Z = \pmatrix{-82.5 & -99.5 \cr -99.5 & -99.99\cr}$$
which is indefinite (its determinant is negative).

Comment: Right, but I guess the ordering defined with arbitrary matrices is preserved.